# Groupby and combine in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe that looks something like this - with `name,count` being `strings` and `id` being an `int`.

| name | count | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | 01122 |
| abc | 123 | 55432 |
| abc | 123 | 33432 |
| abc | 123 | 34786 |
| xyz | 232 | 36126 |
| xyz | 232 | 67437 |

Using pandas - I'm trying to get to something like

| name | count | id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| abc | 123 | 01122,55432,33432,34786 |
| xyz | 232 | 36126,67437 |

I thought something like below would work - but it doesn't seem to actually join the list.

`df.groupby(['name','count'])['id'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x))).reset_index()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `astype()`+`groupby()`+`agg()`:

```
out=df.astype({'id':'str'}).groupby(['name','count'],as_index=False)['id'].agg(','.join)
#df.groupby(['name','count'],as_index=False)['id'].agg(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x)))
```

output of out:

```
    name    count   id
0   abc     123     1122,55432,33432,34786
1   xyz     232     36126,67437
```

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually think my original query worked too but I was mistaking not creating a new df with it in my code (would appreciate feedback if you think it doesnt). Your's works great! thankyou!

Comment: @Tim it is also working `df.groupby(['name','count'])['id'].apply(lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x))).reset_index()`

Comment: @Tim also use `lambda x: ','.join(map(str, x))` in the agg function bcz even if it is anonymous function but is is faster than `astype({'id':'str'})` for a single column